# Redirecting an external link in the menu so it opens in a position of the template and not in a new tab

Tags: joomla2.5

I just wrotge a php file and I puted it in the file manager in the site so you can get to it with the url like this: http://www.eatwizard.com/project081113/ ... select.php

Now I created a link in the menu a the main page, and I wanted to deliver the page into the mainframe (to a position of the template), instead the link is being opened in a new tab, any ideas of how I can change it? thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0):

You should use the "target" attribute of the  tag.

Syntax :

```
<a target="_blank|_self|_parent|_top|framename">
```

In your case, specify the destination framename.

For instance :

```
<a target="my_rightupper_frame" href="http://....." >Here's a link</a>
```

See details : http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp

Comment: The problem is that Joomla doesn`t use frames, it uses positions in the templates that are installed